# how to check if a variable was changed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

his is my save function

```
ManageFiles c = MangeFiles();
TextEditingController code = TextEditingController();
autoSave(){
  c.saveTXT(code.text);
}
```

I wish every time a user types a word run and save, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Hello and welcome ! There is an `onChanged` field for TextField which fires everytime a user types something. Give it a go.

Comment: I'm not using a TextFild

Comment: Where does the user "type" the word then ?

Comment: I'm using something called CodeField

Comment: he types into this CodeFeild which is like an editor

Comment: Can we get the code for the CodeField then ? Most probably you need to expose the `onChanged` of `CodeField`. Is it from a package?

Comment: Yes, it is a package and does not have onChanged

Comment: I wanted to implement something like a notepad, and this CodeField was the closest I thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save your user's input each time he types anything just simply use onChanged method in your TextField to call your method. It will invoke it each time new value is typed

OR

You can use TextEditingController and add a listener to it. It will be invoked when its value is changed

sample:

```
late final TextEditingController _textEditing;

@override
void initState() {
    _textEditing = TextEditingController();
    _textEditing.addListener(() {
        final String value = _textEditing.value.text;

        // YOUR CODE
    });
    super.initState();
}
```

Comment: he types inside a CodeField which is like an editor I got from the dart site

Comment: I checked the package and found out it has InputCodeController which also has addListener method just like TextEditingController. I think that will invoke your method each time value changes